# Migration Approach For BT2006 R2 to Azure Windows Service

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

As we know there is no more Microsoft support for BizTalk 2006. Its going to end soon, so I am working on POC/Analysis for migrating BizTalk 2006 R2 Application to latest BizTalk version.

Is there any options available like taking the BizTalk 2006 R2 application with required run time components as a msi package and deploy into Azure windows VM (as a service)?

I got below information while investigating on this.

For Azure platform, they have provided two options

1. Azure VM hosting (As like on premise, but  BizTalk will be in cloud VM), but again not BizTalk 2006 R2 as support is going to end
2. Azure BizTalk Services (PaaS Model). Again this is also not just a migration. we have to develop from the scratch. Maybe we can re-use the schema, Maps (by using tool for converting .btm to .trfm), there is no orchestration. So we need to do artifacts migration not package migration.

Is there any options available as highlighted above?

Comment: Moving to MABS would be a major effort, and would likely require an entire rewrite of your integration - assuming that your current integration doesn't rely on functionality that MABS doesn't currently handle well.  You'd likely be better served giong through the process of upgrading to 2013R2 and running that on a VM,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You easiest upgrade path is to BizTalk Server 2013 R2 running in an Azure VM.  Migrating to an Azure Services model, if even possible, will essentially require the entire app to be refactored to support that runtime.

While it is possible that your BizTalk Server 2006 app will run unchanged on BizTalk Server 2013 R2, that is not a recommendable solution.  You should upgrade the source Projects to the 2013 R2 SDK.  This does require a double hop to 2006R2/2009 -> 2013R2.

Deploying to a BizTalk Server VM on Azure is no different than deploying to an on-prem BizTalk instance so don't worry about that.  You would still use .msi's generated from BT Admin of BTDF.

Comment: Thanks John. Actually my application is developed in BizTalk 2006 R2. In that case i don't need a double hop I can directly upgrade to 2013R2 running in Azure VM. Please confirm whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, you can upgrade the app in Visual Studio directly to VS 2013.